# On conjectures about the arithmetic function that counts the number of Sophie Germain primes

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, experimental-mathematics

In this post we denote (for a fixed positive integer or real number $x$) as $$\operatorname{Germain}(x)=\#\{\text{ primes }p\leq x\,|\,2p+1\text{ is also prime}\}$$
the arithmetic function that counts the number of primes $p$ less than a given positive real $x$ satisfying that $2p+1$ is also prime. As general reference I add the article from Wikipedia [*Sophie Germain prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) that refers that is unproven the existence of infinitely many Sophie Germain primes, and the articles also from Wikipedia [*Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) and for [*Legendre's constant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant). I was inspired in these articles and a few experiments using Pari/GP scripts to state the following conjectures.

**Conjecture 1.** *One has* $$\operatorname{Germain}(x+y)\leq \operatorname{Germain}(x)+\operatorname{Germain}(y)$$
*for all integer* $x\geq 2$ *and all integer* $y\geq 2$.

**Conjecture 2.** *One has that* $\forall x>87$
$$\operatorname{Germain}(x)<2C\frac{x}{\log^2 x-20}$$
*where* $C$ *denotes the Hardy–Littlewood's twin prime constant.*

> **Question.** Are these known, or is it possible to prove or refute any of previous conjectures? Can you find counterexamples for these or add heuristics to know what about the veracity of this kind of conjectures? **Many thanks.**

I've tested the first conjecture only for the segments of integers $2\leq x,y\leq 500$. The second conjecture is true for the segment $88\leq x\leq 25000$, but my belief is that is false, I've tested different constants $\mu$ in the expression $2C\frac{x}{\log^2 x-\mu}$ that are approximately $\mu\approx 20$. I can add in a comment the scripts written in Pari/GP that I've used to check it.

### References:

[1] G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood, *Some Problems of 'Partitio Numerorum.' III. On the Expression of a Number as a Sum of Primes*, Acta Math. (44),  J. E. (1923) pp. 1–70.

Comment: Conjecture $1$ probably is false, too. The reasons to believe this are the same as for not believing this for $\pi(x)$ itself. So one doesn't believe that $\pi(x+y)\le \pi(x)+\pi(y)$ because it would be incompatible with the (more favoured) generalised twin prime conjecture - see Tenenbaum and Mendes France.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help @DietrichBurde . I accept your words.

Comment: I evoke that maybe it is even possible to find counterexamples for small numbers, I don't know.

Comment: Germain($n$) should be rougly $n/(\log^2(n)/2)$. It follows from the prime number theorem that probability $n$ is prime is $1\\log(n)$ and $2n+1$ is $2\\log(n)$, the combined probability is $2/\log^2(n)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @J.Linne

Comment: I've edited the post on MathOverflow with identifier **428616** and same title *On conjectures about the arithmetic function that counts the number of Sophie Germain primes*

Comment: Here it is as a link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428616/on-conjectures-about-the-arithmetic-function-that-counts-the-number-of-sophie-ge